# How to write images, swf's, videos and anything else that is stored on a website to a file on my computer using streams

Tags: java, stream, web

I'm trying to write a program that copies a website to my harddrive. This is easy enough to do just copying over the source and saving it as an html file, but In doing that you can't access any of the pictures, videos etc offline. I was wondering if there is a way to do this using an input/output stream and if so how exactly to do it...

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: I understand that basically there are two parts to this, 
1) copying the relevant file to my HD
and 2) changing the source code to look for the file on my harddrive rather than online

The part I need help with is copying the file over from the net to my HD.

^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `URL` of the file to be downloaded then you can simply do it using `apache commons-io`

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File);
```

**EDIT :**
This code will download a zip file on your desktop.

```
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile;
public static void Download() {

        URL dl = null;
        File fl = null;
        try {
            fl = new File(System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/") + "/Desktop/Screenshots.zip");
            dl = new URL("http://example.com/uploads/Screenshots.zip");
            copyURLToFile(dl, fl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```